# How can I render a row in a dataTable that groups rows according to one of the fields of the bean in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I'm pretty new to Primefaces and I'm having trouble understanding how it works. I'm trying to create a datatable that will show a series of records that are grouped according to one of the fields (area), with a header row indicating the area of the rows beneath it.  There is a tag in Primefaces (since 6.0.11), "p:headerRow", but it's unavailable for my version, Primefaces 5.3. There is also an attribute in the "column" tag, "groupRow", but it's unavailable for my version as well. One idea that comes to mind is to use a conditional header row that will show the value of area for the following rows, depending on whether the area has changed (if not, do not show the header; if yes, show it). I wanted to use a variable "areaActual" to keep track of the area being rendered, to be compared with the area of the next row in the table. I hope I'm being clear... But the variable does not seem to work, and the header row does not show up as a header (if I remove the "rendered" condition). Please help!

This is the xhtml.:

```
<h:panelGroup id="pgbody" styleClass="backBeanChangeBody" rendered="#{informacionpersonal$kardex.existe}">
        <p:dataTable id="dataTablePrincipal" 
                     style="height:100%;width:100%" value="#{informacionpersonal$kardex.listaKardex}" var="currentRow" rows="10"
                     paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,25,30" reflow="true" >
            <p: rendered="#{!currentRow.area eq areaActual}">
                <p:column id="encabezado" colspan="7">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{areaActual}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <ui:param name="areaActual" value="#{currentRow.area}" />
            <p:row>
                <p:column id="column3"  sortBy="#{currentRow.espAsignatura}">
                    <p:outputLabel id="outputText5" value="#{currentRow.espAsignatura}"/>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Asignatura"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column id="column5" sortBy="#{currentRow.espPeriodoescolar}">
                    <p:outputLabel  value="#{currentRow.espPeriodoescolar}" />                    
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Periodo escolar"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column id="column6" sortBy="#{currentRow.creditos}">
                    <p:outputLabel  value="#{currentRow.creditos}" />                    
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Créditos"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column id="column7" sortBy="#{currentRow.espTipoevaluacion}">
                    <p:outputLabel  value="#{currentRow.espTipoevaluacion}" />                    
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Tipo de evaluación"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column id="column12" sortBy="#{currentRow.calificacion}">
                    <p:outputLabel  value="#{currentRow.calificacion}"/>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Calificación"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>      
            </p:row>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

This is the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "informacionpersonal$kardex")
@ViewScoped
public class kardex extends FacesBean implements Serializable {
private int __placeholder;
private void _init() throws Exception {
    selectOneMenu1DefaultItems.setItems(new String[]{"10", "15", "20", "25", "30"});
}

private FormaModal formaModal = (FormaModal) getValue("#{plantilla.formaModal}");
private Boolean notselectedrow = true;
private DefaultSelectionItems selectOneMenu1DefaultItems = new DefaultSelectionItems();

public DefaultSelectionItems getSelectOneMenu1DefaultItems() {
    return selectOneMenu1DefaultItems;
}

public void setSelectOneMenu1DefaultItems(DefaultSelectionItems dsi) {
    this.selectOneMenu1DefaultItems = dsi;
}

public Boolean getNotselectedrow() {
    return notselectedrow;
}

public void setNotselectedrow(Boolean notselectedrow) {
    this.notselectedrow = notselectedrow;
}

private TableListDataModel tabla;

public TableListDataModel getTabla() {
    return tabla;
}

public void setTabla(TableListDataModel tabla) {
    this.tabla = tabla;
}

// </editor-fold>
private Persona alumno;
private Boolean existe;
private List<VEscHistoriaacademica> listaKardex;

public kardex() {
}
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        _init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log("Page1 Initialization Failure", e);
        throw e instanceof FacesException ? (FacesException) e : new FacesException(e);
    }
    listaKardex = new ArrayList<VEscHistoriaacademica>();
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
}
protected ApplicationBean1 getApplicationBean1() {
    return (ApplicationBean1) getBean("ApplicationBean1");
}
protected Controlador getControlador() {
    return (Controlador) getBean("Controlador");
}
public Persona getAlumno() {
    return alumno;
}
public void setAlumno(Persona alumno) {
    this.alumno = alumno;
    listaKardex = new ArrayList<VEscHistoriaacademica>();
    listaKardex.clear();
    listaKardex = getControlador().findByAlumno(alumno.getId());
    existe = !listaKardex.isEmpty();
}
public List<VEscHistoriaacademica> getListaKardex() {
    return listaKardex;
}
public void setListaKardex(List<VEscHistoriaacademica> listaKardex) {
    this.listaKardex= listaKardex;
}
public Boolean getExiste() {
    return existe;
}
public void setExiste(Boolean existe) {
    this.existe = existe;
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is easily solved. Better to switch to a version that **does** contain this feature.

Comment: I'm working in a team and I guess the consensus is to continue using the older version :/  but thanks anyway, @Kukeltje, I'm trying out the p:subTable tag, I think that might work. Cheers!

Comment: Soooo many new great things coming in 6.2... ;-)